# Accessing the next page using selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

First, I have never used selenium until yesterday.  I was able to scrape the target table correctly after many attempts.

I am currently trying to scrape the tables on sequential pages. It works sometimes and other times it fails immediately.  I have spent hours surfing Google and Stack Overflow, but I have not solve my problem.  I am sure the answer is something simple, but after 8 hours I need to ask a question to the experts in selenium.

My target url is: [RedHat Security Advisories](https://access.redhat.com/security/security-updates/#/security-advisories)

If there is a question on Stack Overflow that answers my problem, please let me know and I will do some my research and testing.

Here are some of the items that I have tried:

Example 1:

```
page_number = 0
while True:
  try:
    page_number += 1

    browser.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",
                           WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="jumpPoint"]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div['
                                                                                                  '2]/dir-pagination-controls/ul/li[str(page_number))]'))))

    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="jumpPoint"]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/dir-pagination-controls/ul/li[str(page_number)').click()

    print(f"Navigating to page {page_number}")

    # I added this because my connection was 
    # being terminated by RedHat
    time.sleep(20)

except (TimeoutException, WebDriverException) as e:
    print("Last page reached")
    break

except Exception as e:
    print (e)
    break
```

Example 2:

```
page_number = 0
  while True:
   try:
     page_number += 1

     browser.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",
                           WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="jumpPoint"]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div['
                                                                                                  '2]/dir-pagination-controls/ul/li[12]'))))

     browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="jumpPoint"]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/dir-pagination-controls/ul/li[12]').click()

     print(f"Navigating to page {page_number}")

     # I added this because my connection was 
     # being terminated by RedHat
     time.sleep(20)

 except (TimeoutException, WebDriverException) as e:
     print("Last page reached")
     break

 except Exception as e:
    print (e)
    break
```

Comment: What's the error when it fails?

Comment: have you considered clicking the next button until exception is caught?  ...attribute contains "ng-click"..

Comment: @pcalkins no, but I can do some additional research on how this would work.

Comment: @NathanielC  I just added a generic exception handler and received this error: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=51498): Max retries exceeded with url

Comment: the webdriver wait would throw a timeout exception at the end of the list.

Comment: the max retries are probably coming from the webdriver wait... it'll keep re-polling... you may need to switch to a sleep here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below logic.

```
lastPage = WebDriverWait(driver,120).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//ul[starts-with(@class,'pagination hidden-xs ng-scope')]/li[starts-with(@ng-repeat,'pageNumber')])[last()]")))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("i.web-icon-plus").click()
pages = lastPage.text
pages = '5'
for pNumber in range(1,int(pages)):
    currentPage = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//ul[starts-with(@class,'pagination hidden-xs ng-scope')]//a[.='" + str(pNumber) + "']")))
    print ("===============================================")
    print("Current Page : " + currentPage.text)
    currentPage.location_once_scrolled_into_view
    currentPage.click()
    WebDriverWait(driver,120).until_not(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#loading")))
    # print rows data here
    rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[starts-with(@class,'cve-table')]/tbody/tr") #<== getting rows here
    for row in rows:
        print (row.text) <== I am printing all row data, if you want cell data please update the logic accordingly
    time.sleep(randint(1, 5)) #<== this step is optional
```

Comment: I'm getting a statement seems to have no effect on this line:  currentPage.location_once_scrolled_into_view.  What is this line for?

Comment: That line will scroll to the page number element. It's equivalent to JavaScript scrollIntoView.

Comment: I ran the code successfully. Sometime page loading is taking more time hence I added 120 seconds.

Comment: Yes, your code is working correctly with the paginations.   I'm currently trying to figure out how to call this line of code: main_table = driver.find_element_by_class_name('cve-table') with your code.

Comment: Check my updated answer with the logic to print the row data from each page.

Comment: I spent about 16 hours trying to resolve this problem myself.  You resolve the issue in minutes!!!  Your code will help me when I'm attempting to scrape other sites using selenium.  THANKS for assisting me!!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can read data directly using url instead of trying for pagination, this will lead to less sync issues because of which script might be failing

1. Use this xpath to get total no of pages for the security-updates table.
   //*[@id="jumpPoint"]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/dir-pagination-controls/ul/li[11]
2. Run loop till page count get from step 1 
   Inside loop pass page number in below url and send get request
   https://access.redhat.com/security/security-updates/#/security-advisories?q=&p=**page_number**&sort=portal_publication_date%20desc&rows=10&portal_advisory_type=Security%20Advisory&documentKind=PortalProduct
3. wait for page to load
4. Read data from table populated on page
5. This process will run till the pagination count
6. Incase you find specific error that site has blocked the user then you can refresh the page with same page_number.