# Not able to extract table for redhat securities using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, python-requests

I want to extract security update table from [security advisories](https://access.redhat.com/security/security-updates/#/security-advisories) and store it in dataframe.

Similarly I want to extract table in this with its URL of products - 
[security](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/security.html)

My code so far is:

```
import requests 
import pandas as pd 

url = "helpx.adobe.com/in/security.html" 
header = { "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36", "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest" } 
r = requests.get(url, headers=header) 
dfs = pd.read_html(r.text) len(dfs) 
df = dfs[0] 
print(df) 
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('PythonExport.xlsx') df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1') writer.save()
```

Comment: import requests
import pandas as pd
url = "https://helpx.adobe.com/in/security.html"
header = {
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}
r = requests.get(url, headers=header)
dfs = pd.read_html(r.text)
len(dfs)
df=dfs[0]
print(df)



writer = pd.ExcelWriter('PythonExport.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()

Comment: So basically you want to crawl a web page . So is your question is how to crawl the web page? or have you written some code for it?

Comment: Use selenium for Redhat and BeautifulSoup for Adobe.

Comment: One of my previous questions focused on scraping one of your target sites:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56449443/accessing-the-next-page-using-selenium

Comment: You can use the [edit] button to make improvements to your question, better than adding code as comments.

Comment: Are you getting an error? What's the problem?  It worked fine for me when I changed it to write a `.xls` file and installed `xlwt`..